# Is it possible to use IComparable to compare entities in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have a POCO class that implements `IComparable`.

```
public interface IEntity : IComparable
{
    long Id { get; set; }

    Func<IEntity, bool> CompareFunction { get; }
}

public abstract class BaseEntity : IEntity
{
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }

    public Func<IEntity, bool> CompareFunction
    {
        get
        {
            Func<IEntity, bool> compare = EvaluateEquivalency;
            return compare;
        }
    }

    public static int Compare(BaseEntity left, BaseEntity right)
    {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(left, right))
        {
            return 0;
        }

        if (object.ReferenceEquals(left, null))
        {
            return -1;
        }

        return left.CompareTo(right);
    }

    public static bool operator ==(BaseEntity left, BaseEntity right)
    {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(left, null))
        {
            return object.ReferenceEquals(right, null);
        }

        return left.Equals(right);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(BaseEntity left, BaseEntity right)
    {
        return !(left == right);
    }

    public static bool operator <(BaseEntity left, BaseEntity right)
    {
        return Compare(left, right) < 0;
    }

    public static bool operator >(BaseEntity left, BaseEntity right)
    {
        return Compare(left, right) > 0;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        IEntity other;

        if (!(obj is IEntity)) return false;

        other = (IEntity)obj;

        if (object.ReferenceEquals(other, null))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return this.CompareTo(other) == 0;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return base.GetHashCode();
    }

    public virtual int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("obj");
        if (!(obj is IEntity)) throw new ArgumentException("obj is not an IEntity");

        if (this.Id == ((IEntity)obj).Id) return 0;

        return -1;
    }

    private bool EvaluateEquivalency(IEntity toCompare)
    {
        return Equals(toCompare);
    }
}
```

There is `DbSet` for my POCO class in my `DbContext`.

However, when I execute `BaseRepository.Exists()` I get a `System.NotSupportedException`.

```
public class BaseRepository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class, IEntity
{
    ...

    private TEntity Exists(TEntity entity)
    {
        return Context.DbSet<TEntity>.FirstOrDefult(i => i.CompareTo(entity) == 0);
    }

    private TEntity ExistsV2(TEntity entity)
    {
        return Context.DbSet<TEntity>.FirstOrDefult(i => i.CompareFunction(entity) == 0);
    }

    ...
}
```

The exception stack trace looks like...

```
System.NotSupportedException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Unable to create a constant value of type '{My POCO Class}'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.
  Source=System.Data.Entity
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.ConstantTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, ConstantExpression linq)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.EqualsTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, BinaryExpression linq)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateLambda(LambdaExpression lambda, DbExpression input)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateLambda(LambdaExpression lambda, DbExpression input, DbExpressionBinding& binding)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, DbExpression& source, DbExpressionBinding& sourceBinding, DbExpression& lambda)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.FirstPredicateTranslatorBase.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, SequenceMethod sequenceMethod)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.Convert()
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
       at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
       at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.<GetElementFunction>b__1[TResult](IEnumerable`1 sequence)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle[TResult](IEnumerable`1 query, Expression queryRoot)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[S](Expression expression)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.DbQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
       at System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
```

When I execute `BaseRepository.ExistsV2()` I get a slightly different `System.NotSupportedException`.

```
System.NotSupportedException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233067
  Message=The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.
  Source=System.Data.Entity
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.NotSupportedTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateLambda(LambdaExpression lambda, DbExpression input)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateLambda(LambdaExpression lambda, DbExpression input, DbExpressionBinding& binding)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, DbExpression& source, DbExpressionBinding& sourceBinding, DbExpression& lambda)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.FirstPredicateTranslatorBase.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, SequenceMethod sequenceMethod)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.Convert()
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
       at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
       at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.<GetElementFunction>b__1[TResult](IEnumerable`1 sequence)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle[TResult](IEnumerable`1 query, Expression queryRoot)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[S](Expression expression)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.DbQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
       at System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
```

I've read the Entity Framework doesn't support `IComparable`?  Is there anyway around this or does anyone know whether the functionality will be available in EF6?

Comment: Throwing an `ArgumentNullException` in `CompareTo` violates the Microsoft guidelines for how `CompareTo` should behave: "By definition, any object compares greater than (or follows) `null`" (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.compareto.aspx); instead you should just return `1` (or any number > 0) when `CompareTo(null)` is invoked.

Comment: I am also having this issue,  I have a a large data set. And using ajax data tables to select pages at a time. I need the orderby to happen sql server side. And i have string columns that have numbers in them, and they don,t order correctly. Neither do IP addresses.  Any solutions to this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't do this.

EF requires all operations to be able to execute 100% server-side. Supporting `IComparable` or `IEquatable` would require EF to be able to translate arbitrary IL into SQL, which it can't yet do.

Otherwise, it would have to pass the entire unfiltered result set to the client. You can achieve exactly this by using `AsEnumerable()`:

```
Context.DbSet<TEntity>.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault(i => i.CompareTo(entity) == 0);
```

This will of course run quite slow though, so I wouldn't recommend it if the table is of any significant size.

Comment: AsEnumerable is bad, it will load all entities in memory.

Comment: Agreed. He asked about using `IComparable`, and I gave him the only way he's going to be able to use it _and_ a warning about why not to.

Comment: @Akash Kava, `AsEnumerable()` will not materialize the collection.

Comment: Well in that case this answer will raise same exception

Comment: I need this to execute on the server.  Sending the the entire list over the wire the client is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatly no (or perhaps a better answer is not easily).

Entity framework can only use methods which it knows how to translate to SQL. This is something that isnt likely to change in any version of SQL. If EF were to understand ICompariable what that really means is that it needs to be able to convert an arbitrary piece of code to SQL.

There are however some alternatives to this. You can define a reusable expression which is implemented in linq and then apply this to your entities in SQL (linq is generally translatable to SQL), this will give you similar behavior but is more complicated to implement. check out linqkit if you want to try this http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx

Comment: I have updated the question to include what I tried to get this to work.  Still getting `System.NotSupportedException`.  Any more ideas?

Comment: @TheMagnificent11 you cant use IComparable it just wont work as it cant convert to SQL. The best you can do is use a reuable expression

Comment: @TheMagnificent11 You can't use `Func<T, bool>`, you need `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`. And you need to use it correctly, which is what LINQKit is for.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible and it will never be possible in future as well because lComparable is part of .Net where else there is no such thing in SQL. Lambda expressions are converted to SQL WHERE clause, they are never executed.

```
  x ⇒ x.CustomerID == 2
```

gets converted to

```
 WHERE CustomerID =2
```

But for your case you can create a Reflection based method.

```
private TEntity Exists(TEntity entity)
{
    Type t= typeof(TEntity) ;
    ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter( t ) ;
    PropertyInfo p = t.GetProperties().First(x => x.GetCustomAttributes( true ).OfType<KeyAttribute>().Any()     ) ;
    Expression e = Expression.Property( pe , p);
    e = Expression.Equal( e, p.GetValue(entity, null) );
    var l = Expression.Lambda<Func <TEntity, boot>>(e , pe) ;
    return Context.DbSet<TEntity>.FirstOrDefult(l);
}
```

Based on your implementation you might have to change KeyAttribute to EdmScalarDataAttribute & check if attribute has key = true or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your base entity as IComparable than you can compare your loaded entities(By lazy loading might be a problem)! Entity framework does not support directly the IComparable interface.

Or you can doing something like that:

```
public abstract class Entity
{
  public int MyCompare(Entity entity)
  {
   ..
   ..
  }
}

private Entity Exists(Entity entity)
{
    return Context.DbSet<Entity>.ToList().FirstOrDefult(i => i.MyCompare(entity) == 0);
}
```

Comment: @AkashKava yes good Point I have Forget the tolist thanks after Tolist() the FirstOrDefult will get FirstOrDefault from IEnumerable Interface and not from Linq To Entities.

Comment: but to ToList() will loads all entities from DB this might be a Problem for performamnce.