# IQueryable.OrderBy is not working with IComparer in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, iqueryable

We have a signature of a method in a IQueryable interface:

```
public static IOrderedQueryable<TSource> OrderBy<TSource, TKey>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> keySelector, IComparer<TKey> comparer);
```

I am trying to implement this call like

```
var result = await DbSet.OrderBy(e => e.Type, new EntityTypeComparer()).ToListAsync();
```

But it throws the exception "The LINQ expression could not be translated".

*Can you share any working examples of IComparer with EF Core? Or how I can implement custom sorting logic for int property in EF Core?*

P.S. [Microsoft docs says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/supported-and-unsupported-linq-methods-linq-to-entities) that IComparer is not supported. But what do we need IQueryable.OrderBy with IComparer parameter for?

Comment: Arbitrary comparers obviously cannot be supported since you can't run C# code on the database end. The replacement depends on exactly what you're doing in your comparer. As to why it's there, some standard comparers like `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase` may well be supported by LINQ providers (which encompass more than just databases, in any case).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57971185/3844386 ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is already explained to this case here [Is it possible to use IComparable to compare entities in Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18692381/is-it-possible-to-use-icomparable-to-compare-entities-in-entity-framework)

The short Answer is No, you cant do that.

EF requires all operations to be able to execute 100% server-side. Supporting IComparable or IEquatable would require EF to be able to translate arbitrary IL into SQL, which it can't yet do.

Comment: I like the hopeful addition of "yet" -- technically it's absolutely feasible to implement an IL interpreter in T-SQL. Performance would be horrific, but let's ignore that bit. :)

Comment: That's true man , I will allow myself to say "maybe they will" just for you :)